# When i want to use 2 dimensional array it returns me undefined

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, multidimensional-array, undefined

I work with database which I input.

I declared array and wanted to push another array in first one.

When I try to use my 2 dimensional array, console returned `undefined`.

```js
let dataAboutCovid = [];
let date, totalCases, todayCases, recovered;
let country = "USA";

//Read file from input
//Control if country exist
//Put data about covid in dataAboutCovid

function readFile(input) {
  let database;

  for (i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {

    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(input.files[i]);

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      database = e.target.result;

      let arrayOfCountry = database.split(`\n`).find((item) => item.includes(country))
      if (!arrayOfCountry) {
        return
      }
      if (arrayOfCountry.slice(0, 3) == ",,,") {
        date = arrayOfCountry.slice(3, this.length).split(",")[1].split(" ")[0];
        totalCases = arrayOfCountry.slice(3, this.length).split(",")[4];
        todayCases = arrayOfCountry.slice(3, this.length).split(",")[5];
        recovered = arrayOfCountry.slice(3, this.length).split(",")[6];
        dataAboutCovid.push([date, totalCases, todayCases, recovered]);
      }
    }
  };

  console.log(dataAboutCovid[1][1])
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you please show the example of the data itself so we can figure out what is wrong from the code? If I guess right, the database becomes array of strings after the split, doesn't it?

Comment: it is excel file

Comment: ,,,Albania,2021-01-03 05:22:52,41.1533,20.1683,58991,1190,34353,23448,Albania,2049.8644798109667,2.017256869691987
,,,Algeria,2021-01-03 05:22:52,28.0339,1.6596,100159,2769,67611,29779,Algeria,228.40733799649877,2.764604279196078
,,,Andorra,2021-01-03 05:22:52,42.5063,1.5218,8166,84,7463,619,Andorra,10568.821588041155,1.0286554004408524

Comment: What are you expecting `this` to be when accessing `this.length`? You may want to log that and make sure it meets your expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two issues.

- When `i` is 0, you would only fill up `dataAboutCovid[0]`, so `dataAboutCovid[1]` is undefined
- There's a possibility that `console.log` is executed before `reader.onload` due to the asynchronous nature of js.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to read a bunch of files rather than just one file and iterating on the split newlines